# Сортировка списка кортежей

Tags: python, python-3.x, сортировка, python-2.x, генераторы

Всем, доброго времени суток!

Есть список кортежей:

```
temp_list = [(1, 3), (5, 4), (6, 2), (4, 1), (3, 6), (2, 5)]
```

Можно ли отсортировать этот список так, чтобы образовалась цепочка:

```
new_list = [(1, 3), (3, 6), (6, 2), (2, 5), (5, 4), (4, 1)]
```

Есть ли красивое решение в стиле python?

С уважением, Игорь

Comment: Список всегда "идеальный"? Такое может быть: `[(1,2) (2,3) (2,4) (4,5) (5,2)]`?

Comment: Построить цепочку для "идеальной части". В нашем случае - идеальный.

Comment: В данном пример жадный метод дает две цепочки, тогда как можно сделать одну.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как насчет такого?

```
temp_list = [(1, 3), (5, 4), (6, 2), (4, 1), (3, 6), (2, 5)]
new_list = [min(temp_list)]
for _ in range(len(temp_list) - 1):
    item = new_list[-1]
    new_list.append(
        next(filter(lambda x: item[1] == x[0], temp_list))
    )

print(new_list)
# [(1, 3), (3, 6), (6, 2), (2, 5), (5, 4), (4, 1)]
```

---

Через словарь:

```
temp_list = [(1, 3), (5, 4), (6, 2), (4, 1), (3, 6), (2, 5)]
d = dict(temp_list)
new_list = [min(temp_list)]
for _ in range(len(temp_list) - 1):
    x = new_list[-1][1]
    new_list.append((x, d.get(x)))

print(new_list)
# [(1, 3), (3, 6), (6, 2), (2, 5), (5, 4), (4, 1)]
```

Comment: заметил что вы изменили вопрос, а в чем заключается изменение, добавили теги?

Comment: @finally, ага, под вопросом есть ссылка вида "Изменен " тыкайте и сможете посмотреть историю изменений

Answer (score 3):

Возможно все, смотря как стараться)
а по поводу красоты - каждому свое, у кого то красота в эффективности, у кого то в краткости кода

```py
for i in range(len(temp_list)):
    for j in range(len(temp_list)):
        if temp_list[i][1] == temp_list[j][0]:
            try:
                temp_list[i + 1], temp_list[j] = temp_list[j], temp_list[i + 1]
            except IndexError:
                pass
```

Answer (score 3):

Как вариант:

```
d = { i:j for i,j in [(1, 3), (5, 4), (6, 2), (4, 1), (3, 6), (2, 5)] }

def f(d, k, l):
    nk = d.get(k)
    new_list.append([k, nk])
    k = nk
    l -= 1
    if not l:
        return new_list
    return f(d, k, l)

new_list = []
print(f(d, 1, len(d)))  # [[1, 3], [3, 6], [6, 2], [2, 5], [5, 4], [4, 1]] 

new_list = []
print(f(d, 2, len(d)))  # [[2, 5], [5, 4], [4, 1], [1, 3], [3, 6], [6, 2]]

new_list = []
print(f(d, 3, len(d)))  # [[3, 6], [6, 2], [2, 5], [5, 4], [4, 1], [1, 3]]

new_list = []
print(f(d, 4, len(d)))  # [[4, 1], [1, 3], [3, 6], [6, 2], [2, 5], [5, 4]]

new_list = []
print(f(d, 5, len(d)))  # [[5, 4], [4, 1], [1, 3], [3, 6], [6, 2], [2, 5]]

new_list = []
print(f(d, 6, len(d)))  # [[6, 2], [2, 5], [5, 4], [4, 1], [1, 3], [3, 6]]

new_list = []
print(f(d, 7, len(d)))  # [[7, None], [None, None], [None, None], [None, None], [None, None], [None, None]]
```

Comment: Только, пожалуйста, без глобальных переменных :) сделайте передачу `new_list` в качестве параметра рекурсивной функции