# Построение (не сортировка) списка на основе предложенного правила

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть список ранее отобранных ребер графа:
    my_root = [(4, 5), (1, 2), (2, 3), (7, 8]
Есть новый кандидат на добавление в root:
    new_item = (3, 4)
Необходимо построить максимальную цепочку, используя new_item в качестве базового. Должно получиться:

```
my_root =[(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5)]
```

Для решения я использовал код:

```
path = [new_item]  

for _ in range(len(my_root)):
    left_item = path[0]
    right_item = path[-1]
    path.append(next(filter(lambda x: right_item[1] == x[0], my_root)))
    path.insert(0, next(filter(lambda x: left_item[0] == x[1], my_root)))
```

Ошибка возникает, когда filter(lambda x: right_item[1] == x[0], my_root) ничего не возвращает.
Как лучше решить эту задачу в стиле python?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Сортировка списка кортежей](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1037560/%d0%a1%d0%be%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%b9)

Comment: `Как лучше решить эту задачу в стиле python?` - в том вопросе вам уже ответили как лучше решить. Если у вас вопрос именно по проблемам в данном коде, так и пишите.

Comment: `Построение (не сортировка) списка на основе предложенного правила` - так у вас и в предыдущем вопросе по факту не сортировка, а построение списка было. Через сортировку списка эту задачу не решить. Любой ответ из того вопроса подходит к этому вопросу, поэтому фактически это дубль.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оператор next вторым параметром принимает значение, которое он вернёт вместо StopIteration. Можно записать в список некоторое пустое значение (None, None) не являющееся ребром. После чего удалить из пути все такие рёбра.

```
my_root = [(4, 5), (1, 2), (2, 3), (7, 8)]

stop_item = (None, None)
new_item = (3, 4)
path = [new_item]

for _ in range(len(my_root)):
    left_item = path[0]
    right_item = path[-1]
    path.append(next(filter(lambda x: right_item[1] == x[0], my_root), stop_item))
    path.insert(0, next(filter(lambda x: left_item[0] == x[1], my_root), stop_item))

while stop_item in path:
    path.pop(path.index(stop_item))
print(path)
```

Но это далеко не самое производительное решение поставленной задачи само по себе. Не стоит использовать цикл for там где не все его итерации являются значимыми.

Comment: Условие if можно внести в тело цикла и тогда необходимости в удалении не будет. Суть ответа принята, спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

```
path = [new_item]
poor_points = list()

for _ in range(len(my_root)):
    left_item = path[0]
    right_item = path[-1]

    next_item = next(filter(lambda x: right_item[1] == x[0], my_root), False)
    if next_item:
        path.append(next_item)

    prev_item = next(filter(lambda x: left_item[0] == x[1], my_root), False)
    if prev_item:
        path.insert(0, prev_item)
```